# Updating all Listbox/Checkboxes on Button push "refreshing the GUI" Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a fairly large GUI so I won't be able to put all the code here for it to work. So as a generalized question: I am trying to update all available data for the GUI without destroying the window and rebuilding it, on a button push. 
My current approach is to "unlock" the text boxes that contain the checkboxes with the available lists of data and delete them with something like this:

```
def refreshfunciton(): #called on button push elsewhere
        self.Tab1Text.configure(state='normal')
        self.Tab2Text.configure(state='normal')
        self.Tab3Text.configure(state='normal')
        self.Tab4Text.configure(state='normal')
        self.Tab5Text.configure(state='normal')
        #to unlock the text boxes so changes can be made

        #below "Tab1CheckButton" ect are lists established elsewhere
        for i in self.Tab1CheckButton:
            i.pack_forget()

        for i in self.Tab2CheckButton:
            i.pack_forget()

        for i in self.Tab3CheckButton:
            i.pack_forget()

      #code going here to update the lists that the checkboxes pull from

        self.createCheckBoxes()
     #function that creates all the checkboxes above. 

     #code to lock the text boxes that contain the check boxes.
```

If there is an easier why without destroying the GUI and rebuilding it, I am very open to doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest clearing the listbox/checkbox and rewriting the contents:

You can delete the contents of the Listbox with `listbox.delete(0,END)`

You can disable the Checkbox with `checkbox.config(state=DISABLED)`

Then, rewrite and readjust the listbox/checkboxes via a list of data, inserting each data value one by one in a for loop, e.g.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    listbox.insert("{}".format(data[i]), END)
```